# Efficient bulkification of callouts

Tags: callout, bulkification

I have a requirement to update a property at the geolocation of an account record. Decided that triggers or any synchronous apex isn't the way to go forward primarily due to governor limits. I would like to update the weather details of the location of all the associated accounts once in a day. Please provide any suggestions on as to how to implement this. Does a scheduled batch sound good? Any other viable options? Thanks in advance.

Comment: at first, I would recommend to find api geolocation service that allow bulk record processing. In that case, if you update 200 accounts, you can use 1 callout, and would not hit any limits

Comment: That is really useful information. Thanks Kurunve. What do you think my strategy shall be for updating the weather of those those individual geolocation points in the account rec itself. The web service is not bulkifiable.

Comment: if you have spare time, you can create proxy app on heroku f.e. or whenever, and make those bulkified. About your last idea -- I didn't get that

Comment: @kurunve Time limits make heroku a non viable option :( . I was earlier talking about updating a bunch of account records with their current weather. Thanks for your help.

Comment: lets go deeper. You create service in heroku, that allow to get some addresses and account ids. From heroku there is a one cron that automatically get data that you need one by one,  and update records in salesforce as soon as data from geolocation is returned. SO, there would be almost no time limit=)

Comment: The Appleman Advanced Apex 3rd Edition addresses this issue in his scalable async apex pattern. well worth buying the book and reading the solution as it can be applied to all your async apex needs